# Outlook Vba to Set Screen Updating in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, outlook

I run an Outlook macro to copy data from outloo0k to an excel spreadsheet, it is very slow and I would like to turn off screenupdating. How can I do this>?

Comment: ^ Making sure that you have a reference to the Excel Application. Obviously in Outlook, `Application` refers to the Outlook instance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) property to turn screen updating off to speed up your macro code. You won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster. Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends.